# eager fetch objects in collections

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have `Cat` objects mapped using Hibernate similar to the one mentioned in the manual: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/ (example 4.1) . Fields in the `Cat` class are set to be lazily fetched, but I would like to write a HQL query that eagerly fetches a `Cat` object along with all her kittens. I tried using `from Cat as c inner join fetch c.kitten`, but that doesn't fully fetch the fields of each of the kittens.

My question is: how I can write a single HQL query that eagerly fetches all items in a collection? I am aware of [Eager fetching collections in Hibernate with ScrollableResults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217590/eager-fetching-collections-in-hibernate-with-scrollableresults) but I don't think there is a solution there (and if possible I also don't want to change the mapping files to eager fetching).

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't fully fetch the fields of each of kittens"? Have you get your solution?